# Random Bug started to show up

Tags: ms-access, vba

Have been running a program for weeks now, that enters groomers times into a database. Have never had a problem with it.

Yesterday, the 1st time entered worked fine, no problems.
The second time entered threw an error.

Didn't have time to look at it yesterday, so just manually entered all the times.

Today, the same thing. 1st time entered, worked perfectly, no problems.
2nd time entered, throws an error.

The code stops on this line:

```
If DCount("[PetID]", "[TimeLog]", strCriteria) > 0 Then
```

With Run-Time 3464, Data type mismatch in criteria expression

The entire code for that section:

```
'Set variables for error checking duplicates
Dim pid As Integer
Dim aptdate As Date
pid = CmbPetName.Column(2)
    'MsgBox (pid)
aptdate = txtAptDate.Value
    'MsgBox (aptdate)
Dim strCriteria As String

'Set Criteria for DCount()
strCriteria = "([PetID] = '" & pid & "') And ([ApptDate] = #" & aptdate & "#)"
    'MsgBox (strCriteria)

'Error checking for duplicates
If DCount("[PetID]", "[TimeLog]", strCriteria) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Record Already Exists")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

At a total loss for why all of a sudden this is happening, and why it is random

ANY advise on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your date expression:

```
strCriteria = "([PetID] = '" & pid & "') And ([ApptDate] = #" & Format(aptdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```

And if pid is numeric, not text:

```
strCriteria = "([PetID] = " & pid & ") And ([ApptDate] = #" & Format(aptdate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```

Comment: 978 entries later is when this started happening, formatted '"&pid&"' to "&pid&" seemed to fix it, so far lol